# Convert custom tiny-YOLOv3 to a tensorflow format

Tags: deep-learning, data-conversion

After having tried all solutions I have found on every github, I couldn't find a way to convert a customly trained YOLOv3 from darknet to a tensorflow format (keras, tensorflow, tflite)

By custom I mean:

- I changed the number of class to 1
- I set the image size to 576x576
- I set the number of channels to 1 (grayscale images)

So far I am happy with the results on darknet, but for my application I need TFlite and I can't find working method for conversion that suits my case.

Anyone have succeed in doing something similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the resulting .weights file for your custom model?

If so, the following project by peace195 may help:
https://github.com/peace195/tensorflow-lite-YOLOv3

**EDIT:**

In the above link, use convert_weights_pb.py file to convert your .weights file to a .pb file.

Then use the .pb file as a saved model and convert it to a .tflite model using the following command.

*tflite_convert --saved_model_dir=saved_model/ --output_file yolo_v3.tflite --saved_model_signature_key='predict'*

Thanks Anton Menshov for your suggestion on improving the answer.

Comment: Thanks @AntonMenshov. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simplest and easy repo. Author has done a wonderful job and it works well with yolov3, yolv3-tiny and yolov-4. Please don't forget to change the coco.names under classes if you are training on custom classes.

[Git link for the code](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite)